# Não consigo criar um usuario no mongo pelo docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

Estou executando o comando:

```
mongo exec -it mongodb mongo --host localhost -u admin -p 3613 --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('testando').createUser({user: 'spirit', pw: '3613', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'testando'}]})"
```

Mas recebo o erro:

> Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-it'
>       try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe --help' for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando deveria ser

```
docker exec -it ...
```